# Function that can execute every other function

Tags: c, process, stack, pthreads

I'm studying threads in university and I would like to make a library in C that does similar things to pthread but using processes and then compare the performances of both.

In other words I would like to make function like:

```
function execute_function(func_ptr, args)
```

Where `func_ptr` is a generic pointer to function like `void* (*f)()` and args...well I don't know...
The problem here is obviously that I don't know inside of `execute_function` the number and types of the arguments of the function pointed.

I wondered if there was a way to "manually" allocate arguments on the stack and then call the function, in this case I would add an argument for the total argument size.

The only solution I came up with is to wrap the function pointed by func_ptr with a function that takes as single parameter a valist, this function would then "unwrap" the valist as the wrapped function would expect, but it seems far from how pthread_create works.

Do someone have an idea?

Comment: Just require a function of a fixed signature the way threads do

Comment: `it seems far from how pthread_create works.` how does it work? pthread_create requires exactly `void *(*f)(void*)` function, no other.

Comment: pthread_create does not work how you think it does.

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand, but the question is about how to pass arguments to that function. If you know how it is done I would really appreciate if you posted and answer

Comment: @user253751 mine was an assumption, I don't understand much about pthread code, can you explain me how it works?

Comment: `how to pass arguments to that function` To which function? I do not understand. `pthread_create` passes the 4th argument to the function pointer taken as 3rd argument. I.e. `pthread_create(&thread, 0, func, arg)` calls `func(arg)`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @KamilCuk ok maybe I failed to understand how it works. Just for clarification, if I want to pass to pthread_create a function that takes multiple parameters I should make a structure made by the arguments and put it into the 4th argument right? Who splits the arguments back (if it is done) to pass it to the function pointed?. Is it pthread with some kind of magical trick or is it the function pointer itself?

Comment: `Who splits the arguments back` No one, or maybe _you_ split the arguments back, if you want to. The argument is a `void *` it stays a `void *` until _you_ split it. Passing any other function other than `void *(void *)` to pthread_create is invalid.

Comment: @EmanueleFalanga There is no magic. There is one argument, and it's a void* - end of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_create` receives a function with exactly `void *(void *)` signature and when executing the thread it passes the 4th argument as the function argument.

To call your own function, typically you create a structure with your arguments, pack your arguments into the structure and just use the structure inside your function.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct yourargs {
  int arg1;
  char arg2;
};
void *yourfunction(struct yourargs *this) { 
    printf("%d %c\n", this->arg1, this->arg2);
    return 0;
}


void *yourfunction_trampoline(void *cookie) {
    struct yourargs this = *(struct yourargs *)cookie;
    free(cookie);
    return yourfunction(&this);
}

int main() {
    struct yourargs *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
    *a = (struct yourargs){1, 'a'};
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, 0, yourfunction_trampoline, a);
    pthread_join(p, 0);
}
```

You could unpack the structure, but it's easier to just have it together anyway.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *yourfunction(int arg1, char arg2) { 
    printf("%d %c\n", arg1, arg2);
    return 0;
}

struct yourargs {
  int arg1;
  char arg2;
};
void *yourfunction_trampoline(void *cookie) {
    struct yourargs arg = *(struct yourargs *)cookie;
    free(cookie);
    return yourfunction(arg.arg1, arg.arg2);
}

int main() {
    struct yourargs *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
    *a = (struct yourargs){1, 'a'};
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, 0, yourfunction_trampoline, a);
    pthread_join(p, 0);
}
```

Between the real function and actual function, typically you add a trampoline function with the signature `void *(void *)` in which to cast or unpack the structure. As I understand, you are searching for that trampoline function.

Now, bottom line, you "want" `std::thread(yourfunction, 1, 'a')` in C. That is not possible. There are no lambdas, objects, templates, constructors nor destructors in C programming language. You have to *write*, type it out, all the names and objects and types you are going to use and free and allocate memory yourself. You can hide your code behind intricate macros, in which case the code becomes a burden to maintain. You could also use extensions to C programming language, like GCC nested functions or "blocks" lambdas in clang or OpenMP, but they are extensions. In C, you type it out, write the trampoline function, allocate arguments, unpack the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not provide facilities for this, but [libffi](https://github.com/libffi/libffi) does.

However, more commonly for situations such as you describe, the library is given a pointer to `void`, which is actually memory containing data it does not know about, and a function to call that accepts that function. That function knows how to use the data and how to call the actual function to be measured. So, to measure the performance of `foo`, you would write `fooDriver` to call `foo`, and it is `fooDriver` you would pass to the library instead of `foo`.

Answer (score -2):

Use macro.

```
#define execute_function(funcptr, ...) (funcptr)(__VA_ARGS__)

int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int (*ptr)(int,int) = mul;

int main(void)
{
    int result = execute_function(printf, "%d %d\n", 1,12);
    size_t len = execute_function(strlen, "%d %d\n");
    printf("%d\n", execute_function(ptr, 2,7));
}
```